# Passar banco de dados txt para mysql

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, microsoft-excel

Olá, eu estou com um arquivo txt onde eu queria pegar seu conteudo para por em um banco de dados, mas estou com dificuldades segue um exemplo de como esta o arquivo:

```
[03471]
Nome=fulano
Idade=20
Sexo=Masculino
[05232]
Nome=fulana
Idade=17
Sexo=feminino
```

Eu queria jogar para um banco de dados com colunas, algo assim:

```
 ID   CODIGO  NOME     IDADE  SEXO
----  ------  -------  -----  ---------
 1     03471  Fulano      20  Masculino
 2     05232  Fulana      17  Feminino
```

Pode ate ser passando dessa forma pro excel que depois eu exporto pro mysql.

Se alguem puder me ajudar pq são mais de 8 mil dados desses.

Comment: Porque passar para excel se é possível passar diretamente para o banco?

Comment: Bem-vindo JP Ferreira, caso alguma resposta resolva seu problema, não esqueça de marca-la como aceita, veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 2):

Podemos, com PHP, abrir o arquivo txt, manipular e com o resultado obtido, inserir no banco de dados.

Tabela do banco de dados

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ID | CODIGO | NOME | IDADE | SEXO
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**PHP comentado**

```
//Criamos uma função que irá retornar o conteúdo do arquivo.
function ler(){
    //Variável arquivo armazena o nome e extensão do arquivo.
    $arquivo = "arquivo.txt";

    //Variável $fp armazena a conexão com o arquivo e o tipo de ação.
    $fp = fopen($arquivo, "r");

    //Lê o conteúdo do arquivo aberto.
    $conteudo = fread($fp, filesize($arquivo));

    //Fecha o arquivo.
    fclose($fp);

    //retorna o conteúdo.
    return $conteudo;
}


//colocamos o conteudo em uma variavel 
$var = ler();

//retiramos espaços, quebra de linhas e assemelhados para colocar tudo em uma linha
$var= trim($var);
$var = preg_replace(array("/\t/", "/\s{2,}/", "/\n/", "/\r/"), array("", " ", " ", " "), $var);

/**************************************************************************************** 
a partir daqui efetuamos algumas substituições de maneira que possamos construir o
VALUES do INSERT que deverá ser assim
('','03471','fulano','20','Masculino'),('','fulana','17','feminino'), etc........)
*****************************************************************************************/

$substituir = array(" Nome=", " Idade=", " Sexo=");
$result = str_replace($substituir, "','", $var);
$result = str_replace("]", "", $result);
$result = str_replace("[", "'),('','", $result);
$result = substr($result, 3)."')";

/****************************************************************************************/

//aqui um exemplo  de insert com MySQLi

 $link = new mysqli ("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "Nome_DB");

 $sql = "INSERT INTO suatabela VALUES $result";

 $res = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
```

---

---

> **A titulo de teste fiz um loop para gravar mais linhas no arquivo txt**

```
//Criamos uma função que recebe um texto como parâmetro.
function gravar($texto){
    //Variável arquivo armazena o nome e extensão do arquivo.
    $arquivo = "arquivo.txt";

    //Variável $fp armazena a conexão com o arquivo e o tipo de ação.
    $fp = fopen($arquivo, "a+");

    //Escreve no arquivo aberto.
    fwrite($fp, $texto);

    //Fecha o arquivo.
    fclose($fp);
}

for ($k = 0 ; $k < 7998; $k++){

gravar("
[03471]
Nome=fulano
Idade=20
Sexo=Masculino
[05232]
Nome=fulana
Idade=17
Sexo=feminino
[01952]
Nome=Leo
Idade=66
Sexo=Masculino");

}
```

> **e logo após executei o arquivo para abrir o txt e inserir os dados no banco**

**Resultado**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

A forma mais simples seria realizando a importação a partir de um arquivo csv.

Para isso precisaria através do excel ou equivalente e salvar ou exportar como CSV.

A partir disso pode utilizar o comand LOAD DATA (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)

No windows essa importação pode ocorrer através de interface gráfica a partir do programa https://www.heidisql.com/

Comment: mas o problema dele é justamente passar da forma em registros um abaixo do outro para a forma de colunas.

Comment: Tem razão, desculpe acabei entendo errado o problema